# How to implement a generic method in Repository to make joins in linq

Tags: c#, linq, repository-pattern

Hello I have a linq query that makes several joins on tables and which eventually returns me a single row.

For the time being, I have used the generic method `GetAll()` that returns the single row.

The query that I have written is as follows:

```
from h in _repositoryWorkers.GetAll()
join p in _repositoryJobs.GetAll() on h.Id equals p.THI_N_ID
join q in _repositoryHome.GetAll() on h.Id equals q.THI_N_ID

    public Repository()
    {
        this.context = new WorkersContext();
        entities = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {

            return entities.AsEnumerable<T>();

    }
```

What I want to achieve is the following as an example:

```
from w in repo.Query<Worker>()
join e in repo.Query<XEntity>() on ...
```

I do not want to use a List that returns me only a single row. I just want to return an object of this row.

Please advise.

Comment: Something tells me that generic repository should not be used here for a complex query.

Comment: What is the alternative to be used ?

Comment: Just query DbContext directly, wrap it in a service. EF is a generic repository with Unit-Of-Work in itself already, you are building a crutch on top of it to make your own life harder.

Answer (score 3):

In isolation, I would write something like:

```
var result = context.Worker()
    .Include(worker => worker.XEntity)
    .Where(worker => worker.ID == id)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

result will either be the single Worker entity with XEntity populated or null if there is no entry with a matching id.

How do you make it generic though?

I've tried a lot of things over the last few years and in the end, I find that specific methods work best.
So I'll have a generic base repository for the simple stuff but then I'll extend that when I need to do things like this.

So I would have a specific repository for the Worker entity that extends the generic base.
It would have a method like:

```
public Worker GetByIdWithXEntity(id)
{
    this.Queryable()
        .Include(worker => worker.XEntity)
        .Where(worker => worker.ID == id)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

(Queryable is a protected method on the base repository)

This approach is a bit of a pita with large projects but I've found that it works very nicely as it keeps all the data access logic in the Repo, it makes unit testing your services simple and it's very clear exactly what's going on.

That said, if anyone has a better way, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Hi. But I am making joins with several tables. That's why I want to avoid using the `GetAll()` method that returns an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: That's okay. You can just chain the Include statements together to include whatever tables you want. With this approach, the query is executed in the DB, only one DB call is needed and only one entry is returned (if any).